Dynamically set the Property name to be the name of the Type(typeof(T).Name)
var appsettings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AppSettings<PersonModel>>(configData);

class AppSettings<T>
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = typeof(T).Name)]
    public T dynproperty { get; set; }
}

Appsettings.json content:
{
  "PersonModel": {
    "name": "tempname",
    "active": true
  },
  "CarType":{
    "segment": "sedan",
    "seating" 5
  }
}

In the above class, T will be any model class.
The name of dynproperty has to be set dynamically so that during deserialization from a JSON, the respective model type will be picked by the deserializer.
PS: I am open to any other method, too.

You certainly can't do it with attributes, they can only accept constant values.  I can't provide a full answer as I'm not extremely familiar with json.net but I think you have to use a JsonConverter.
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeWithJsonConverters.htm

@Tarazed You are right, it only takes constant values. That's why I had hard time finding a solution. Tried several ways, all leading to dead ends.

@Tarazed is right. You should use a JsonConverter. Something like this should work:
class DynamicPropertyNameConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var jObject = JObject.Load(reader);

        var genericType = objectType.GenericTypeArguments[0];
        var genericTypeName = genericType.Name;

        var token = jObject[genericTypeName];

        if (token == null)
        {
            throw new JsonSerializationException($"Property '{genericTypeName}' not found.");
        }

        return token.ToObject(genericType, serializer);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

Your AppSettings class should then have the property and attribute changed, like so:
class AppSettings<T>
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(DynamicPropertyNameConverter))]
    public T dynproperty { get; set; }
}

You can then retrieve the settings:
var personSettings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AppSettings<PersonModel>>(configData);
var carSettings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AppSettings<CarModel>>(configData);

So you have to create PersonModel and CarModel, which you should have btw.
To access the data in personSettings, you then use, say, personSettings.dynproperty.name.

Your solution doesn't seem to rightly recognize the property name. I have tried implementing the solution, it doesn't works. Sharing this fiddler link for your reference : Fiddler Code Refernce
